# Issue installing Google chrome on fedora 11 using YUM

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fedora11

While i'm installing Google chrome on my Fedora 11. It give below issue

```
[root@vi65 /]# yum -y install chromium
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
http://spot.fedorapeople.org/chromium/F11/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: chromium. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 11 has been unsupported for a little while now, so you should not expect people working on the Fedora Project such as Spot to continue maintaining software for it. Either update your system to a supported version of Fedora, or install [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) instead.